# Why is Locale final in Java?

Tags: java, internationalization, icu4j

The class [`java.util.Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) is declared as `final`, which means that nothing can extend it.

The [ICU4J project](http://site.icu-project.org/home/why-use-icu4j) have written an extension of this class - [`com.ibm.icu.util.ULocale`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/ULocale.html) (which is also `final`), but because of this it can't inherit or be used easily instead of `Locale`.

What would the reason for this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending locales is not something that can easily be done without modifying the underlying system, due to the deep integration into those systems that locales have.

If you *could* extend `Locale` to add some additional properties, then none of the classes that currently accept a `Locale` would know how to handle them.

Assuming you've got a JDK with simply `Locale` support and you *could* pass in a `ULocale` that has a more in-depth support (such as specifying the calendar and digits to use other than the default for the underlying locale), then you couldn't expect code that accepts a traditional JDK `Locale` to support those features.